# could not connect to server:Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connection

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am having issues with Postgres. I try opening pgAdmin and it shows this error...[image]

Comment: The error message in your question's title is a totally different error then the one in the screen shot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It isn't different. If i scroll, i see the error in my title..